# Make view scrolling with a recyclerview and appbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-recyclerview

How to make some custom view to be on top of `RecyclerView` and scroll with it?

-appbar with parallax image - collapsing when i scroll up

-my custom view - moving with recycler

-recyclerview

I nearly achieved such a behavior using `nestedscrollview` inside `collapsingtoolbalayout` but a problem that `nestedscrollview` cuts my custom view's content if content is longer than screen.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     tools:context="ru.example.app.PublicationViewActivity">  
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
      android:id="@+id/app_bar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@color/white_light"
      app:elevation="0dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        >

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/background"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="@dimen/grid_x_25"
          android:scaleType="centerCrop"
          app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

      <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
          android:id="@+id/toolbar"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
          android:background="@drawable/gradient_action_bar"
          app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/grid_x_7"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/grid_x_2">

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
              style="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
      </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

      <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
          android:id="@+id/content"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/grid_x_25"
          android:background="@color/white_light">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

          <include layout="@layout/content_interests"/>

          <View
              style="@style/MainDivider"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="1px"
              android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
        </LinearLayout>
      </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
  </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
      android:id="@+id/recycler"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
  </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: you tried `LinearLayout` height as `match_parent`?

Comment: @pRaNaY yes, i tried. I have tried various methods.

Comment: may i found same case [here](http://ivankocijan.xyz/android-nestedscrollview/) for your answer!!

Comment: @pRaNaY thank you for your reply, but i have tried this method too. That case is not what i want to achieve.